# Exposing variable to all twig templates when using silex and twig together

Tags: php, twig, silex

I use standalone silex and twig (so without Symfony). I have an object that I need to create for all silex routes and that needs to be exposed to all twig templates. How can I do this?

As an example: in the example below I'd rather not have to include $myObject in the `use` clause of a Silex route and I'd also rather not have to include it to the array in the `render` function when kicking off twig. Since they are needed in all routes and all templates it will just clutter up the code.

```
$myObject = new MyObject();
$app->get('/test', function () use ($app, $myObject) {     
    return $app['twig']->render(
      'someTemplate.twig',
      array('myObject' => $myObject)
    );    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to your globals:

```
$app["twig"]->addGlobal("mObject", $myObject);
```